# ¿Porque al correr mi codigo no ejecuta ningun cambio en pantalla?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, compilador, compilar

codeblocks edicion

Buenas mi problema continua con el compilador del codeblocks o la forma en la que
compila, en varios cursos de youtube he visto que no tienen este problema y ninguno 
me a podido dar razon. Lo que pasa es que al momento de correr un programa el compilador sigue ejecutando las instrucciones anteriores, me explico con un codigo,

```
 bool logico;
    int a=4, b=6;
    logico = a <= b;

    cout << logico;
```

con esto al compilar me bota por pantalla 1 bueno hasta ahi bien ahora, si hago una
modificacion,

```
bool logico;
    int a=4, b=6;
    logico = a >= b;

cout << logico;
```

con esto me deberia aparecer en pantalla 0, pero no me sigue apareciendo 1.

```
bool logico;

    logico = false;

    cout << logico;
```

Y si lo pongo asi en false sigue botando 1 es como si no compilara o no sobreescribiera el ejecutable, claro yo estoy guardando el codigo cada vez que lo modifico. Si me podrian ayudar me salvarian la vida de verdad estoy cansado con esto es estresante.

Comment: acabo de compilar tu algoritmo, solo te falta "construir" dale al icono del engranaje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente debes obtener un valor de 0

```
bool logico;
logico = false;
cout << logico;
```

Vuelve a construir tu proyecto (**Rebuild**) dando click al icono azul

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O mediante el menu, **Build** > **Rebuild**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola no quiero sonar muy inexperto pero el rebuild no me aparece habilitado. Inclusive note que guardar archivo ctrl +s no aparece habilitado creo que este es el problema Jorgesys.Gracias

Comment: entonces realiza solo un Build, comentame que sucedeç?

Comment: La aplicacion de pantalla no aparece, y los mensaje aparece build file:"notarget" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) === build finished : 0error (s) (0 minute (s), 0 seconds

Comment: Volvi ha hacerlo y aparecio error: id returned 1 exit status.

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys, ya vi el problema, como le dije anteriormente esta desabilitado el guardar por lo tanto al darle ctrl + s, y compilaba me sacaba este error, asi que mire en las opciones de file que dice guardar todo (alt + shift + s ) y compila normal, ahora a mirar como hago para habilitar estas opciones ya que son muchas las que no puedo utilizar incluido el rebuild, gracias habia dado muchas vueltas en esto y no me habia percatado de nada hasta ahora, enserio gracias.

Comment: si te sirvio la respuesta dale al visto de la respuesta Diego